# C++17 variable templates Fibonacci series nth number

Tags: c++, templates, variables, c++17, c++20

Here is a sample code to find nth numberin Fibonacci series

```
template <int32_t val>
constexpr auto fib = fib<val - 1> + fib<val - 2>;
template <>
constexpr auto fib<0> = 0;
template <>
constexpr auto fib<1> = 1;

std::cout << fib<46> << std::endl; //1836311903

std::cout << fib<47> << std::endl; // error here
```

Successfully works till 46th value but unable to compile 47th value what can be the reason I think variable size limit is the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The 47th Fibonacci number is 2,971,215,073. During its calculation with the given algorithm, the `int32_t` overflows. Signed integer overflow is undefined behavior, and it is a fallacy to expect any specific result.

Comment: A constant expression that *would* have undefined behavior is simply not a constant expression, so the behavior of this program is fully **specified** (with the alternative possibility that the implementation does not provide the integer type in question).

Comment: @DavisHerring How can the behavior of the program be specified when signed integer overflow occurs, which is undefined behavior?

Comment: @j6t `int32_t` is parameter value output is `auto fib` .

Comment: @j6t: I just said this: constexpr evaluation is just different in this regard.  (Conceptually, the implementation **considers** the evaluation, without actually performing it, and deems it non-constant if undefined behavior would result.  In many contexts, that non-constancy is an error, so the (runtime) evaluation never happens.)

Comment: @Davis I agree with you , if evaluations are performed then no need of constexpr.

Answer (score -1):

Variable size limit.
Stack size limit could be the problem.

Comment: There certainly are limits in practice on template instantiation depth, but I’m not sure what these limits mean here.

Comment: Most probably the resources limit to a process, can be checked with “ulimit -a” command on Linux.